# Getting list based on text lxml

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

I have some html like:

```
... 
    <table width="100%">
            <tr class="blueborder">
              <td colspan="2" class="blackbold">Some Other Text</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <table width="100%">     
        <tr class="upcoming">
          <td class="lists" >
            <ul>
              <li> List1 Element1</li>
              <li> List1 Element2</li>
              <li> List1 Element3</li>
            </ul>
          </td>
        </tr>
     </table>
      <table width="100%">
        <tr class="blueborder">
          <td colspan="2" class="blackbold">Signaling Text</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table width="100%">
        <tr class="upcoming">
          <td class="lists" >
            <ul>
              <li> List2 Element1</li>
              <li> List2 Element2</li>
              <li> List2 Element3</li>
            </ul>
          </td>
        </tr>
     </table>   
...
```

I was using `employees = root.xpath('.//td[@class = "lists"]/ul/li/text()')`, but this grabs both list elements. I'd just like to grab lists 2, except they have the same properties (class and such). The only difference is `<td colspan="2" class="blackbold">Signaling Text</td>` comes before the list I want. Is there some way to indicate to only get this list after this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the following td after the tr with the text `Signaling Text`:

```
h = """ <table width="100%">
            <tr class="blueborder">
              <td colspan="2" class="blackbold">Some Other Text</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <table width="100%">
        <tr class="upcoming">
          <td class="lists" >
            <ul>
              <li> List1 Element1</li>
              <li> List1 Element2</li>
              <li> List1 Element3</li>
            </ul>
          </td>
        </tr>
     </table>
      <table width="100%">
        <tr class="blueborder">
          <td colspan="2" class="blackbold">Signaling Text</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table width="100%">
        <tr class="upcoming">
          <td class="lists" >
            <ul>
              <li> List2 Element1</li>
              <li> List2 Element2</li>
              <li> List2 Element3</li>
            </ul>
          </td>
        </tr>
     </table>  """

from lxml import html
tree = html.fromstring(h)
print(tree.xpath('//td[contains(.,"Signaling Text")]/following::td[@class = "lists"]/ul/li/text()'))
```

Which would give you:

```
[' List2 Element1', ' List2 Element2', ' List2 Element3']
```

Or if you were sure it was the second occurrence:

```
tree.xpath('(//td[@class = "lists"])[2]/ul/li/text()')
```

Comment: I knew there had to be some simple solution. Thanks!